# resize mask without changing the size of a polygon within the mask

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, mask

I am trying to resize a polygon within a mask while keeping the size of mask same with opencv.

1. I have created a mask with mask = np.zeros_like(img).
2. I have created a polygon with points with polyfill method.
3. Now I need to reduce the size of of this polygon by  certain % while the size of the mask should be same.
4. Is there any way to reduce the size of polygon by percentage?
5. I reduced the size of the mask with the polygon by reducing the width and height.
6. Now can I increase the size of mask without changing the size of polygon?

Comment: You could resize both, image and drawn polygon and afterwards copy the mask to a subimage of s bigger image.

Comment: Thank you. How can I resize the polygon?

Comment: Just resize the drawn polygon by resizing the image where it's drawn on.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to resize the polygon while keeping the size of the mask same.

Comment: resize mask + drawn polygon and copy the result to a subimage of the mask that has unchanged size

Comment: Thanks. I resized the mask. Now how do I copy this (say 90% of the original mask) to the original mask. I need help for this..

Comment: I can only tell you for C++. Search for something like 'copy numpy subimage'

Comment: Thank you. I will find something similar in python. You have guided me how to do it. Thank you